# How Can I Change Url in aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Hi I have a navigate url inside my custom tag like below.

```
<gtc:linkbutton navigateurl="/Customer/Information/Information.aspx" </gtc:linkbutton>
```

I want to add prefix to beginning of the url with dynamically like below but it does not work.

```
<gtc:linkbutton navigateurl="'<%# Constants.Prefix %>'/Customer/Information/Information.aspx" </gtc:linkbutton>
```

I also add namespace before Constants.Prefix but it does not work.

Constants.Prefix is equals to "General" and this constant is in the another class not code behind.
So after that my expectation is

```
navigateurl="General/Customer/Information/Information.aspx"
```

I cant add this prefix manually because there are more then thousands code like that so I have to use Constants.Prefix and replace all navigate urls.

Comment: Use `NavigateUrl='<%# Constants.Prefix + "/Customer/Information/Information.aspx" %>'`. And use `DataBind();` in Page_load if the control is not inside a GridView, Repeater etc.

Comment: @VDWWD Thanks this worked but how can I do this without using DataBind().

Comment: You don't. It is a DataBinding Expression. It is needed. But you could set it from code behind `linkbuttonID.NavigateUrl = Constants.Prefix + "/Customer/Information/Information.aspx";`